# Eliminar espacios repetidos entre palabras en los campos de un DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Quiero eliminar los espacios repetidos en los campos de un DataFrame. Se que para eliminar espacios al principio y al final se utiliza la función strip(), incluso saltos de linea. Sin embargo, el problema no es eso. En el archivo tipo csv se encuentran campos que contienen más espacios entre las palabras. La siguiente tabla es una muestra de prueba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo original contiene 223,000 registros, pero al momento de ejecutar la parte para eliminar espacios repetidos que existen entre las palabras, la ejecución dura demasiado tiempo y por el momento no he encontrado una solución a este proceso.´

Les adjunto el codigo:

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv("prueba2.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(file)
df = df.fillna('')

#Limpio los espacios en blanco de las columnas
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')

columnas = list()
for name in df.columns:
    columnas.append(str(name))

#Limpio los espacios en blanco que están al principio y final
for nombre in columnas:
    df[nombre] = df[nombre].astype(str).str.strip()

#En este ciclo es donde se tarda en terminar la ejecución.
for nombre in columnas:
    for value in df[nombre].values:
        val  = str(value)
        d = " ".join(val.split())
        df[nombre] = df[nombre].replace(value, d)

df.to_csv("final.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lo posible evita usar bucles para modificar Dataframes y Series. Los métodos de Pandas son más rápidos que los bucles.

Aquí te ofrezco una solución usando el método apply de los objetos Series de Pandas:

###### Código

```
import pandas as pd
import random


# genero un Dataframe donde cada columna contiene una secuencia formada aleatoriamente con "a" y " ".
# Este DataFrame tendrá 200.000 registros.
df = pd.DataFrame([("".join(random.choice((" ", "a")) for _ in range(10)), "".join(random.choice((" ", "a")) for _ in range(10))) for i in range(200000)])

print(df)

for name in df.columns:
    # Uso apply junto a una función auxiliar.
    df[name] = df[name].apply(lambda value:" ".join(str(value).strip().split()))

print(df)
```

###### Produce

```
                 0           1
0            aa      a  a  aaa
1       a  aa  aaa   aa a aaaa
2       a  a  a aa   aaa   a  
3           a aaaa  a   a a a 
4       a aa   aaa   a  a  a  
...            ...         ...
199995   aa    aaa   aa a   a 
199996   aaa  a a   aa     aaa
199997  aaaaa a aa  a aaaa  aa
199998  aaa aaa a   a aa a  aa
199999   aaaaaa a    aaa  a a 

[200000 rows x 2 columns]
                 0          1
0               aa    a a aaa
1         a aa aaa  aa a aaaa
2         a a a aa      aaa a
3           a aaaa    a a a a
4         a aa aaa      a a a
...            ...        ...
199995      aa aaa     aa a a
199996     aaa a a     aa aaa
199997  aaaaa a aa  a aaaa aa
199998   aaa aaa a  a aa a aa
199999    aaaaaa a    aaa a a

[200000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Al menos en mi computadora no se tarda ni un segundo. Si no te funciona o tienes alguna duda dime c:

Comment: Tu solución es muy rápida en verdad, gracias.

Comment: De nada Jesus A c: